# How to set white color font in IBM Team Concert pending changes area?

Tags: eclipse, rational-team-concert

i use IBM Rtc Eclipse IDE and i set the background to dark, but now in Pending Changes area, all the repository workspaces labels have dark font, so i see dark on dark.

[image]

How can i set the white font in preferences section of Eclipse?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse and go to the "Preferences" section. On a Mac, go to "Eclipse" > "Preferences". On a Windows PC, go to "Window" > "Preferences".

In the "Preferences" window, expand the "General" section and select "Appearance".

In the "Appearance" section, click on the "Colors and Fonts" tab.

In the "Colors and Fonts" tab, expand the "Basic" folder and select "Text Font".

In the "Text Font" section, click on the "Edit" button next to the "Foreground" property.

In the "Color" window that appears, select the white color and click "OK".

Click "Apply" and then "OK" to close the "Preferences" window.

Comment: Thank you for the reply: the problem is that clicking on "tex font" as suggested, it open a window in which i can only edit the font type, the style and the font size. I don't have a color window....